# Error reading a image in Windows 10 Mobile

Tags: c#, image, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I have an issue with a simple image gallery after I choose an image, I sent it to another screen in Windows 10, it works perfect but when I try in my phone, it crashes without a reason, my code is the following one:

XAML code:

```
<Page
    x:Class="Stop_Diabetes.Pages.Camera"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Stop_Diabetes.Pages"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="#227EC2" Loaded="Page_Loaded">
    
    <Page.Resources>
        <local:ImageConverter x:Key="imageConverter"/>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="imageTemplate">
            <Grid Width="190" Height="130">
                <Image Source="{Binding Path=Thumbnail, 
            Converter={StaticResource imageConverter}}" Tapped="Image_Tapped"
            Width="200" Height="200"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
        <CollectionViewSource 
        x:Name="picturesSource"/>
    </Page.Resources>
    
    <Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="stkGallery" Canvas.ZIndex="15" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <GridView x:Name="gvPictures" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="150"  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource picturesSource}}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource imageTemplate}"  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapGrid Orientation="Vertical"></WrapGrid>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemsPanel>
            </GridView>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

C# important code:

```
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    List<string> fileTypeFilter = new List<string>();
    fileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
    fileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
    fileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
    fileTypeFilter.Add(".gif");
    fileTypeFilter.Add(".bmp");
    //Define thr query to iterate thriugh all the subfolders 
    var pictureQueryOptions = new QueryOptions(CommonFileQuery.OrderByDate, fileTypeFilter);
    //Read through all the subfolders. 
    pictureQueryOptions.FolderDepth = FolderDepth.Deep;
    //Apply the query on the PicturesLibrary 
    var pictureQuery = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(pictureQueryOptions);
    // 
    var picturesInformation = new FileInformationFactory(pictureQuery, ThumbnailMode.PicturesView);
    picturesSource.Source = picturesInformation.GetVirtualizedFilesVector();
}

private async void Image_Tapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Image img = (Image)sender;
    FileInformation fi = img.DataContext as FileInformation;
    if (fi != null)
    {
        string path = fi.Name;
        //do something with the path...

        var pStorage = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;

        StorageFile file = await pStorage.GetFileAsync(path);

        ImageProperties imgProp = await file.Properties.GetImagePropertiesAsync();

        using (var imgStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
        {
            WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)imgProp.Width, (int)imgProp.Height);
            bitmap.SetSource(imgStream);

            Frame.Navigate(typeof(Crop), bitmap);
        }
    }
}

public class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            var img = (IRandomAccessStream)value;
            var picture = new BitmapImage();
            picture.SetSource(img);
            return picture;
        }
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

My issue happens here:

***StorageFile file = await pStorage.GetFileAsync(path);***

The PC opens the image perfectly but, when I'm on the phone it says:

***Message = "The system cannot find the file specified.\r\n"***

It's strange because the images are loaded but it cannot open it later, I have tried different options as the ID, Path, etc. and no one works. Does anyone know what should I change in Windows 10 Mobile?

This is more or less how it should look the result of the current code:
[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fileinfo class has an openAsync and OpenReadAsync method why not use them?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br207562

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.bulkaccess.fileinformation.openreadasync

Here is the code you should change

```
 using (var imgStream = await fi.OpenReadAsync())
```

Comment: I'm already using it here: using (var imgStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
            {
                WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)imgProp.Width, (int)imgProp.Height);
                bitmap.SetSource(imgStream);

                Frame.Navigate(typeof(Crop), bitmap);
            }
But you still need to specify the file that you're trying to open.